# How can rewrite the code with pure playwright codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, playwright-python

I want to get all the `a` elements `href` attribute in the webpage `https://learningenglish.voanews.com/z/1581`:

```
from lxml import html
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel='chrome',headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "https://learningenglish.voanews.com/z/1581"
    page.goto(url,wait_until= "networkidle")
    doc = html.fromstring(page.content())
    elements = doc.xpath('//div[@class="media-block__content"]//a')
    for e in elements:
        print(e.attrib['href'])
```

It can print all `a` elements `href` address,try to fulfill same function with pure playwright codes,failed .

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel='chrome',headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "https://learningenglish.voanews.com/z/1581"
    page.goto(url,wait_until= "networkidle")
    elements = page.locator('//div[@class="media-block__content"]//a')
    for e in elements:
        print(e.get_attribute('href'))
```

It encounter error:

```
TypeError: 'Locator' object is not iterable
```

How can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `evaluate_all`:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome", headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "<Your URL>"
    page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
    hrefs = (
        page.locator(".media-block__content a")
            .evaluate_all("els => els.map(e => e.href)")
    )
    print(hrefs)
```

Note that I've used a CSS selector rather than an XPath, which are generally harder to read and maintain and usually not necessary.

Also, the data you want can be gathered without waiting for network idle, so `"domcontentloaded"` will run a bit faster.

In fact, since the data you want is baked into the static HTML, you probably don't need to run JS, allow requests beyond the root HTML document, or even use Playwright at all. A simple HTTP request and BeautifulSoup is sufficient to get the data:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "<Your URL>"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
hrefs = [x["href"] for x in soup.select(".media-block__content a")]
print(hrefs)
```

Playwright:

```
real 0m0.770s
user 0m0.427s
sys  0m0.127s
```

Requests/BeautifulSoup:

```
real 0m0.260s
user 0m0.189s
sys  0m0.009s
```